# toString in the java code

Tags: java, string

The following is my java code snippet:

```
static String sortChars(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return chars.toString();
}
```

I invoke above function by using:

```
String result = sortChars(s);
```

But the result does not meet my expectation:for example,the s="are", the result="aer". However, when I use:

```
return new String(chars)
```

It works.
Could somebody tell me the reason of it. Thanks

Comment: What is your expectation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `char[]` class does not override the default `Object`'s `toString()` implementation, it does not return a string composed by the characters in the char array, but the **char[] class name + hash code**. For example: `arr[C@19821f`.

Comment: Prob worth mentioning this is because an array is an `Object` and doesn't override `toString()` therefore you get `Object.toString()` which is what creates that output.

Comment: FWIW *all* array types don't have toString, that's why there are utility methods in `java.util.Arrays` class.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` returns a string representation of the Object. You can look at it as a description of the object.
`new String(chars)` will give you a `String` with the content of the `char` array.

Use `toString()` if you want to represent an Object to the user or in a log, use `new String()` if you want to get a `String` object that is the same as the content of your array

Answer (score 0):

Note that, among the constructors for a Java String is one that accepts a character array.  That converts the character array into a string as you would expect, and it is the correct choice for what you are doing.